# MVC3 Dialog display from controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am calling controller action method from dialog box from view. I want to return to same dialog box in same view. what return type should I specify in controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [Progressive enhancement tutorial with ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery](http://matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery/). It provides a pretty simple example on how to update a dialog box with new content by adding **jQuery** to perform the requests needed for updating the **UI**.

Hope it helps!